# selection sort up to a zth highest position python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

i'm looking to implement a selection sort algorithm to sort a unsorted list/array, this is what i have gotten at the moment:

```
list1 = [14,3,2,21,23,12,3,4]#unsorted array
z = 3
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i, len(list1)):
        if list1[i] < list1[j]:     
            list1[i], list1[j] = list1[j], list1[i]

print(list1)
```

The problem i'm facing is to get the z'th highest items. ie, print the highest item up until index z

So should print:

```
[23,21,14]
```

It should return the number of item comparisons made (but must be a selection sort algorithm). And shouldn't make anymore comparisons than it needs too (should stop the algorithm once the z'th highest item is found)

update:
I have tried adjusting the interactive python implementation... I just cant get my head around it

this is what i have

```
def selectionSort(alist, k):
    count = 0
    while count < k:
        for fillslot in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
            print(count)
            count += 1
            positionOfMax = 0
            for location in range(1,fillslot+1):
                if alist[location] < alist[positionOfMax]:
                    positionOfMax = location

            temp = alist[fillslot]
            alist[fillslot] = alist[positionOfMax]
            alist[positionOfMax] = temp

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
selectionSort(alist , 3)
print(alist)
```

This prints:

```
0
1
2
3 # should it not stop here since count is less than k?
4
5
6
7
[93, 77, 55, 54, 44, 31, 26, 20, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this python implementation

> `http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheSelectionSort.html`

To people who are not much aware about the algo, It not only compare but also places the largest item to the last place, second largest item to the second largest place. Doing so, we are able to increase the pace of sorting algorithm.

Hope it may help.

Comment: ok so using the interactive python example, can i not just put a while loop in front of the first for loop and have a count in the for loop? then say while this count is less than the value z do the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def limitedInsertionSort(L, z):
    comps = 0
    if z > len(L):
        raise ValueError("List too small")
    for i,j in itertools.product(range(z), range(len(L))):
        if L[i] < L[j]:
            L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]
        comps += 1
    return comps
```

But of course, since you only care about incrementing comps:

```
def countComps(L, z):
    if z > len(L):
        raise ValueError("List too small")
    comps = 0
    for i,j in itertools.product(range(z), range(len(L))):
        comps += 1
    return comps
```

But then, since you know how many times you increment `comps`, you could just do the multiplication:

```
def countComps(L, z):
    if z > len(L):
        raise ValueError("List too small")
    comps = z*len(L)
    return comps
```